# Uncrustify doesn't support for the new Objective-C syntax of LLVM 4.0

Tags: objective-c, code-formatting, uncrustify, llvm-4.0

I have used [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) for formatting code.

But Uncrustify doesn't support for the new Objective-C syntax of LLVM 4.0.

What am I going to do?

The Code formated by Uncrustify:

```
@interface SJTLLVM4Tester()
@property (strong) NSNumber *number;
@end

@implementation SJTLLVM4Tester
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.number = @'C';
        self.number = @123;
        self.number = @0x123ul;
        self.number = @-1.2e-3f;
        self.number = @YES;

        NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key1":@1,@"key2":@2,@"key3":@3};
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[@1,@2,@3]];

        self.number = dictionary[@"key1"];
        array[0] = self.number;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

The execution result:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest uncrustify release : 0.60.

You can grab it here : 
https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify/archive/uncrustify-0.60.tar.gz

I'm using Brew and had to manually update the URL & SHA1 with `brew edit uncrustify` and then `brew upgrade uncrustify`.

Below is my new formula :

```
require 'formula'

class Uncrustify < Formula
  url 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/uncrustify/uncrustify/uncrustify-0.60/uncrustify-0.60.tar.gz'
  head 'https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify.git'
  homepage 'http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/'
  sha1 '769a7649a1cefb80beff9b67b11b4b87a8cc8e0e'

  def install
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", "--disable-dependency-tracking"
    system "make install"
  end
end
```

Works like a charm now.